# How to lock / set / block variable inside .on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I have a jQuery `AJAX` call that gets data from the server (some text, some links).

Inside `AJAX` success callback function I got a `.on` that is bind to `<a>` that load for me next page and get me the text of the clicked link (let's say stackoverflow.com).

The problem starts here because in the newly loaded page I got anchors...

After every click on anchor links I got new `.text()` value.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,         
    dataType: dataType,                                         
    success: function(data){

        $('.container').append(data);

        $('.container').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var clickLinkName = $(this).text();
        console.log(clickLinkName);
        $('.container').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });

   }
});
```

I would like to know how to lock `clickLinkName` variable. OR any other way to save only first hit.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.. your `.on('click',...)` tells that each anchor in the `.container` (or dynamically added to it) should log its own text value. So isn't it normal if you have different links that each one gives a new text value? What do you exactly want to save, for whom?

Comment: I'm saving `clickLinkName` into file on server. And I want to save only first clicked link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do the trick:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: type,
  dataType: dataType,
  success: function(data) {
    $(".container").append(data);

    var clickLinkName; // Declared here.

    $(".container").on("click", "a", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // If not initialized, initialize.
      if(!clickLinkName) {
        clickLinkName = $(this).text();
      }

      console.log(clickLinkName);
      $(".container").load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
  }
});
```

That would save only the first value in the variable `clickLinkName`. This answers your question, but I'm sure there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: So without var or with const / let I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: clickLinkName is not defined`. And doing `var / let  clickLinkName;` get me same result like at start of my problem.

Comment: @Avartil please check my edited answer in order to understand variables scoping.

Comment: @amedina Well... it was embarrassing easy, thank you for help.